# Rendering a second pass yields a different result

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl

Currently I'm trying to render multiple passes with different shaders in a simple OpenGL application. Here's my (simplified) code:

```
void InitScene()
{
  glViewport(0, 0, mWindowWidth, mWindowHeight);
  glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
  glLoadIdentity();
  glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
  glLoadIdentity();
  glOrtho(0, mWindowWidth, mWindowHeight, 0, -1, 1);

  mFramebufferName = CreateFrameBuffer(mWindowWidth, mWindowHeight);
}


void DrawScene()
{
  glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
  glPushMatrix();

  if(drawDirectlyToScreen)
  {
    // This works fine, image will fill the whole screen

    // Directly draw to the screen
    DrawFullScreenQuad();
  }
  else
  {
    // This does not work. The image from the first pass will only be a small quadrat

    // Draw to frame buffer instead of screen
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, mFramebufferName); 
    DrawFullScreenQuad();
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);

    // Get ready for second pass
    BindFrameBufferTextureAndActivateAnotherShader();

    // Now draw to the screen
    DrawFullScreenQuad();
  }

  glPopMatrix();
}

void DrawFullScreenQuad()
{
  glBegin(GL_QUADS);
  glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 1.0f);  glVertex3f(0.0f, mWindowHeight, 0.0f);
  glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 1.0f);  glVertex3f(mWindowWidth, mWindowHeight, 0.0f);
  glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 0.0f);  glVertex3f(mWindowWidth, 0.0f, 0.0f);
  glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 0.0f);  glVertex3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
  glEnd();
}

void CreateFrameBuffer(int width, int height)
{
  // Generate and bind the frame buffer
  mFramebufferName = 0;
  glGenFramebuffers(1, &mFramebufferName);
  glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, mFramebufferName);

  // Create and bind the render texture
  glGenTextures(1, &mSecondPassRenderTexture);
  glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, mSecondPassRenderTexture);

  // Give an empty image to OpenGL ( the last "0" )
  glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, width, height, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, NULL);

  // Set "mSecondPassRenderTexture" as colour attachement #0
  glFramebufferTexture(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, mSecondPassRenderTexture, 0);

  // Set the list of draw buffers.
  GLenum DrawBuffers[1] = { GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0 };
  glDrawBuffers(1, DrawBuffers); // "1" is the size of DrawBuffers
}
```

When rendering only one pass everything is fine. The image covers the whole screen. When rendering with two passes, the resulting image will only cover a small square area in the top left corner of the screen (see the attached images).

[image: Rendering with one pass]
[image: Rendering a second pass]

The problem seems to come from the first pass. The texture created in that pass is already wrong (i.e. the image is only in the corner, the rest of the texture is black). The second pass then works correctly (i.e. the broken texture is drawn correctly to the whole screen).

So my question is: why does my call to DrawFullScreenQuad() yield different results when

1. Rendering to the screen directly
2. Rendering to a frame buffer (which has the same size as the window)

Comment: Can you provide the code of `CreateFrameBuffer`

Comment: I have added the method's code.

Comment: You may want to try a call to glCheckFramebufferStatus

Comment: I think you somehow messed up with these matrices. BTW, you can draw a full-screen quad if you set all OpenGL matrices to identity, and draw the quad from XY={-1,-1} to XY={+1,+1}. Less setup, more likely to work.

Comment: The glBegin, glEnd stuff is the deprecated fixed function pipeline isn't it? None of this looks familiar to me cause I usually use glDrawArrays and shaders.

Comment: Could it be a viewport problem? Even if I double the size of the quad in the first rendering pass, it doesn't get any bigger than the small square in the top left corner. It is still cut out to the same size...

Comment: Did you check values of mWindowWidth and mWindowHeight before  and inside CreateFrameBuffer() function?

Comment: Your glOrtho looks funny, the Y values mWindowHeight and 0 are in the opposite order I would expect. I'd also prefer that glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION be set first and you leave the matrix mode in MODELVIEW_MATRIX at the end of InitScene

Comment: @HughFisher I assume that glOrtho call is to flip the texture on its Y axis.